# How to read last email in asp?

Tags: asp.net, email, pop3

I use [OpenPop](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Fetch-and-Read-emails-from-POP3-mail-server-using-C-and-VB.Net---Part-I.aspx) to read emails from a POP3 mail server, but it doesn't read emails in order.
How do I get the most recent email?

Comment: `order` is a highly subjective thing and completely dependent upon your sorting.  After you get the results from openpop, just sort them in the order you want.

Comment: I have 100 email Per minute, and don't get all email and sort it, have another solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I using `Mail.dll` (mark emails as seen (read) using Mail.dll [.NET IMAP](http://www.limilabs.com/mail) library and IMAP protocol.)

```
using(Imap imap = new Imap())
{
imap.Connect("imap.example.com");    // or ConnectSSL for SSL
imap.Login("user", "password");

imap.SelectInbox();
List<long> uids = client.Search(Flag.Unseen);
if (uids.Count > 0)
    client.MarkMessageSeenByUID(uids[0]);
    imap.Close();
}
```